# Ask Different swag for top users

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Ask Different t-shirt in your size
- Ask Different die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### T-Shirt

[image: apple.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### Sticker

[image: apple.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Holy f**k awesome! YAY!

Comment: ^ What he said. :)

Comment: Yes! Great! Thank you!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Atwood and the rest of the SE crew!

Comment: @Jeff Thank you very much for "swag" ;) As the (probably not deserved) [still] top user of Ask Different, I believe it is an Honor to be here. I may not be Jon Skeet, but I do my best, time permits. I'm sure the other members of the community, especially those who were here when this began, will also appreciate this. Kudos to everyone!

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome!

Comment: What a generous, classy gesture to the community. Well done.

Comment: Wow... thank, this is really cool of you guys!

Comment: This is so awesome. Thank you guys!

Comment: Thanks a lot! <3

Comment: That's cool, looking forward to receiving the swag!

Comment: woot! thanks @Jeff!

Comment: I can wear it over (or under) my SO shirt :)

Comment: Wow, awesome!  Thanks :-)

Comment: When can we expect to receive them? This is cool.

Comment: @zev 6-8 weeks from the original date

Comment: It's been 4 weeks now, so the packages are at least halfway here :-) Looking forward to it!

Comment: Aha, I see Jeff isn't on the 2 first pages, so you ain't getting one! >:D (maybe I should wait receiving mine before braggin')

Comment: That's great! Waiting patiently for my e-mail...

Comment: @Jeff Is there an update on when these are likely to arrive?

Comment: Has anybody received their's yet?

Comment: I got mine this week and I live in Ireland.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Shoot, I made it to page 2 but I guess I missed the party ;)

Comment: I've not received mine yet... Strange.

Answer (score 3):

My package just arrived in the mail yesterday, and I've already had to fight off coworkers trying to steal the pens and stickers. Thanks guys, this is fantastic!